# Match and replace columns of dataframe by multiple conditions

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

Cheers,
I have two data frames with the following structure.

```
DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     150
American           ATL        10-31-2016     150
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     180
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

Second data frame DF2 has the following structure:

```
DF2:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date          
American           ATL        09-30-2016
Delta              ATL        03-31-2017
```

Now looking up with data frames DF1 and DF2, I would like to alter DF1 to the following data frame.

```
DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     0
American           ATL        10-31-2016     150
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     180
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

The condition is, lookup for Airlines and HeadQ of DF1 from DF2 and if DF1$Date < DF2$Date then make Cost_Index as 0 or else continue with Cost_Index.

I tried, unsuccessfully, with:

```
DF1$Cost_Index <- ifelse(DF1$Airlines == DF2$Airlines & DF1$HeadQ == DF2$HeadQ 
        & DF1$Date < DF2$Date, 0, DF1$Cost_Index)


Warning:
1: In DF1$Airlines == DF2$Airlines : longer object
length is not a multiple of shorter object length". 
2: In<=.default(DF1$Date, DF2$Date) : longer object length is not a
multiple of shorter object length

DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     0
American           ATL        10-31-2016     0
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     0
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Note:

```
str(DF1$Date): Date, format: "2016-10-31"
str(DF2$Date): Date, format: "2016-08-31"
```

Comment: when presenting problems related to data that has dates its really best to provide us with your original data so we know what you're working with, can you provide that? Or at least ``str(DF1)``

Comment: Just added the structure of data frames: @Cyrus Mohammadian

Comment: are you getting an error? if not, what has your above code produced?

Comment: It presents me this warning:" Warning messages:
1: In  DF1$Airlines == DF2$Airlines :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".           2: In `<=.default`(DF1$Date, DF2$Date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the  *conditional joins* feature (since `1.9.8`), I'd do this as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.8+
# convert to data.tables, and Date column to Date class.
setDT(df1)[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")]
setDT(df2)[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")]

df1[df2, on = .(Airlines, HeadQ, Date < Date), # find matching rows based on condition
      Cost_Index := 0L]                        # update column with 0 for those rows

df1
#    Airlines HeadQ       Date Cost_Index
# 1: American   PHX 2016-07-31        220
# 2: American   ATL 2016-08-31          0
# 3: American   ATL 2016-10-31        150
# 4:    Delta   ATL 2016-10-31        180
```

Comment: Why does ``DF1$Cost_Index2<-ifelse(DF1$Airlines==DF2$Airlines & DF1$HeadQ==DF1$HeadQ & DF1$Date<DF2$Date,0,DF1$Cost_Index)`` not produce the same result? Instead, the ``Cost_Index`` associated with ``2016-07-31`` is rendered ``0`` (i.e. ``220`` is replaced by ``0``)

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of `ifelse`, but just run, for example, `DF1$Airlines==DF2$Airlines` see what it gives.. hint: recycling. You can't simply equate two equal/unequal vectors here.. For each row in `DF2`, you've to get all matching rows in `DF1`.

Comment: ahhh! Ok I see, in that case, how about this approach: ``DF1$Cost_Index[DF1$Airlines==DF2$Airlines & DF1$HeadQ ==DF2$HeadQ & DF1$Date<DF2$Date]<-0`` also doesnt produce right output

Comment: with data.table several other functions are masked like "melt" from reshape2, several functions from lubridate.

Comment: data.table has data.table methods for melt/dcast, and date/time methods (which overlap with lubridate). The simplest solution is to load `data.table` *before* loading the other two packages.. Or to use `lubridate::` and `reshape2::` and be explicit.

Comment: How do I install data.table v1.9.7. I am using                                                remove.packages("data.table")
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")